# PHP Switch enter in string Case when integer indexed

Tags: php, exception, integer, switch-statement, case

I don`t know what is wrong. PHP simply assume that index (int) 0 of my array is equivalent to Switch`s first Case and throw an error.

Assuming I enter an array like that:

```
$config = [
    "testA" => true,
    "testB" => 22,
    0 => 0
];
```

My code example:

```
foreach($config as $name => $value) {
    switch($name) {
        case "testA":
            if (!is_bool($value)) throw new \Exception( "Configuration '$name' must be boolean.");
            $this->systemVarA = $value;
            break;
        case "testB":
            if (!is_int($value)) throw new \Exception( "Configuration '$name' must be integer.");
            $this->systemVarB = $value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Of course $config["testA"] and $config["testB] work properly, but when foreach reach $config[0] Case "testA" is triggered and app throw me an exception.

An work around that I`ve got is before Switch, cast variable $name like that:

```
$name = (is_int($name) ? (string)$name : $name); // Used this because I already have other inline if
```

But it seams to be a bug. I`ve tested in PHP 7.1, 7.3 & 7.4 on Windows host.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://3v4l.org/uYHWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because PHP use an == operator in switch section.
When you try to compare int(0) with string "testA" , it always return true.
check it:

```php
if(0 == "some string") echo "Equals!";
```

This code prints "Equals!".

Comment: That is correct... it's caused by the loose type system which tries to "convert" the string contents to Integer.. this process stops as soon as the first non-digit character is encountered (eg. instantly in this example)... the result of the conversion is 0 (zero)

Comment: Got it !! Looking for this "==" comparator problem I found other workaround: `switch(TRUE){case ("testA" === $name): //blah break;}`

Comment: @BrunoNatali see my answer for a cleaner solution

Comment: @StephenR I saw your solution, but I already got this cast method work-around as I mentioned in original question. Talking about "true" trick in switch, I chose to this instead of using if & else if, to preserve nice switch structure and provide a nice visual when other programmer reads my code.

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir's answer correctly identifies the cause.  Here's a fix: convert the test value to string, since you're comparing to strings.

```
switch( (string) $name ) {
    ...
}
```

Yes, you can use the `switch(TRUE){case ("testA" === $name): ... }` "Inversion Trick", but at that point, you might as well just use `elseif`!